# Sql query to create teams

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to assign teams to a series of users.  Data looks like this:

```
UserId  Category    Team
1       A           null
2       A           null
3       B           null
4       B           null
5       A           null
6       B           null
8       A           null
9       B           null
11      B           null
```

Teams should be created by sorting by userid and the first userid becomes the team number and the consecutive A's are part of that team as are the B's that follow.  The first A after the Bs starts a new team.  There will always be at least one A and one B.  So after the update, that data should look like this:

```
UserId  Category    Team
1       A           1
2       A           1
3       B           1
4       B           1
5       A           5
6       B           5
8       A           8
9       B           8
11      B           8
```

EDIT:
Need to add that the user id's will not always increment by 1.  I edited the example data to show what I mean.  Also, the team ID doesn't strictly have to be the id of the first user, as long as they end up grouped properly.  For example, users 1 - 4 could all be on team '1', users 5 and 6 on team '2' and users 8,9 and 11 on team '3'

Comment: and you need a sql solution without scripts?

Comment: @SilentByte - if not with scripts, then with what?

Comment: @SilentByte no, a script is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up going with the following.  It finished on all 3 million+ rows in a half an hour.

```
declare @userid int
declare @team int
declare @category char(1)
declare @lastcategory char(1)
set @userid = 1
set @lastcategory='B'
set @team=0

while @userid is not null 
begin

  select @category = category from users where userid = @userid
  if @category = 'A' and @lastcategory = 'B'
  begin
   set @team = @userid
  end
  update users set team = @team where userid = @userid
  set @lastcategory = @category
  select @userid = MIN(userid) from users where userid > @userid
End
```

Answer (score 4):

First you could label each row with an increasing number.  Then you can use a `left join` to find the previous user.  If the previous user has category `'B'`, and the current one category `'A'`, that means the start of a new team.  The team number is then the last `UserId` that started a new team before the current `UserId`.

Using SQL Server 2008 syntax:

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by UserId) rn
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        )
,       changes as
        (
        select  cur.UserId
        ,       case
                when prev.Category = 'B' and cur.Category = 'A' then cur.UserId
                when prev.Category is null then cur.UserId
                end as Team
        from    numbered cur
        left join
                numbered prev
        on      cur.rn = prev.rn + 1
        )
update  t1
set     Team = team.Team
from    Table1 t1
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 c.Team
        from    changes c
        where   c.UserId <= t1.UserId
                and c.Team is not null
        order by
                c.UserId desc
        ) as team;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2b91/1/0)

Comment: @Kevin: You can use `row_number` to generate a continuous number per row, answer edited

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why, but in the estimate execution plan, this has a surprisingly low estimated cost than the first one did.  Like 1/1000th.

Comment: Well, the estimated execution plan was way off.  Ran overnight and was still going.  I cancelled and am running it on only a fraction of the data to try and see how long it will take to run it on all of it

Comment: An index on `UserId` (preferably clustered) would help, or you could run the query in batches (for users 1-10000 first, for example.)

Comment: I actually just tried that.  I added a clustered index on UserId and Category and trimmed it down to the first 10,000.  Still running after half hour

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with userCTE as
(
  select UserId
    , Category
    , Team = UserId
  from users where UserId = 1
  union all
  select users.UserId
    , users.Category
    , Team = case when users.Category = 'A' and userCTE.Category = 'B' then users.UserId else userCTE.Team end
  from userCTE
    inner join users on users.UserId = userCTE.UserId + 1
)
update users
set Team = userCTE.Team
from users
  inner join userCTE on users.UserId = userCTE.UserId
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3818a/1).

**Edit:**

You can update the CTE to get this to go:

```
with userOrder as
(
  select *
    , userRank = row_number() over (order by userId)
  from users
)
, userCTE as
(
  select UserId
    , Category
    , Team = UserId
    , userRank
  from userOrder where UserId = (select min(UserId) from users)
  union all
  select users.UserId
    , users.Category
    , Team = case when users.Category = 'A' and userCTE.Category = 'B' then users.UserId else userCTE.Team end
    , users.userRank
  from userCTE
    inner join userOrder users on users.userRank = userCTE.userRank + 1
)
update users
set Team = userCTE.Team
from users
  inner join userCTE on users.UserId = userCTE.UserId
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91eb9/5).

**Edit:**

For larger datasets you'll need to add the `maxrecursion` query hint; I've edited the previous queries to show this. From Books Online:

> Specifies the maximum number of recursions allowed for this query.
>   number is a nonnegative integer between 0 and 32767. When 0 is
>   specified, no limit is applied.

In this case I've set it to `0`, i.e. not limit on recursion.

[Query Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181714.aspx).

Comment: Updated now; shamelessly stole the Row_Number() idea from @Andomar (you should totally accept his answer), but I thought it would be interesting to apply it to a CTE solution.

Comment: @IanPreston getting the following error: Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: You need to add the *MAXRECURSION* hint... See edit for details.